# Problems after lvm resize

Tags: linux, bash, filesystems, lvm, ext4

`fsck -l` gives:

```
hacker3000@highpower:~$      sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/loop0: 86,9 MiB, 91099136 bytes, 177928 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 91,1 MiB, 95494144 bytes, 186512 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 89,5 MiB, 93835264 bytes, 183272 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 698,7 GiB, 750156374016 bytes, 1465149168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: B701F493-49B6-4611-A226-5FBFCECC0F44

Device       Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048      4095      2048    1M BIOS boot
/dev/sda2     4096   2101247   2097152    1G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  2101248 206901247 204800000 97,7G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv: 4 GiB, 4294967296 bytes, 8388608 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

but at ssh login i get:

```
login as: hacker3000
hacker3000@highpower's password:
Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-43-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

  System information as of Tue Jan 29 10:28:11 UTC 2019

  System load:  0.0               Processes:              134
  Usage of /:   95.3% of 3.87GB   Users logged in:        0
  Memory usage: 4%                IP address for enp0s25: 192.168.178.3
  Swap usage:   0%

  => / is using 95.3% of 3.87GB

 * MicroK8s is Kubernetes in a snap. Made by devs for devs.
   One quick install on a workstation, VM, or appliance.

   - [Removed link]

 * Full K8s GPU support is now available!

   - https://blog.ubuntu.com/2018/12/10/using-gpgpus-with-kubernetes


94 Software-Pakete können aktualisiert werden.
0 Aktualisierungen sind Sicherheitsaktualisierungen.


Last login: Tue Jan 29 10:08:35 2019 from 192.168.178.43
```

also bash cant autocomplete with tab:

```
-bash: cannot create temp file for here-document: No space left on device
-bash: cannot create temp file for here-document: No space left on device
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely that your root partition is > 95% full and the filesystem is not letting non-root users write to it, as is standard for ext filesystems (which should be kept well below 90% full)

The solution is to increase the size of the ext4 root partition or delete stuff on it. Realistically, unless your setup is very static (especially logs not being written to that block device) you will want more then a 4 gig root partition as 5% of that is a paltry 200 megs.

Alternatively (and i've never done it as little good can come from it) you can use tune2fs -m X to tell the ext filesystem to reserve X% space. Expect a perfornance hit (due to fragmentation) at the minimum if you do this.

Comment: If this had not solved your issue, please add the output of "pvs;vgs;lvs;df" which will show your partitioning and mounts. If your root partition is supposed to be bigger then 4gigs then we need to see if the block device irs backing onto needs to be resized or if the partition just needs to be grown.

Comment: THE FS IS 90 GIGS BIG!(look at 1st output) Linux just wont get this!

Comment: did you eaven read everythin?!

Comment: Your output unambiguously shows the root FS is 4 gigs (it shows this in 3 places on your output actually) - The output which explains exactly the cause is - "Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv: 4 GiB."

Comment: BTW, you may not want to be rude to those you ask to help you - your comment "did you eaven read everythin?!" is offensive. I manage Linux storage systems at an enterprise level and know *exactly* what your issues can be, and more then 1 way to fix them (there are 3 likely alternatives). Also, to give as good as I get - learn to read, you have no 90gig partitions, you have ~90 meg loopback devices and a ~97gig partition tagged as a Linux one which is not being used/mounted as such.

Comment: sry but ??? what du you mean with "you have ~90 meg loopback devices and a ~97gig partition tagged as a Linux one which is not being used/mounted as such"?

Comment: ive just resiset the 700 gig partition wich DEFENETLY was the root one, to 90 gig for moval to a smaller hdd cus the old one was spitting out s.m.a.r.t errors

Comment: That is not what the fsck -l output you provided says - You might want to go back and reread it. You might also want to provide the information I requested in my first comment - assuming you are not just trolling.